# Windows 11 in beta channel of insider program

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates, windows-insider

I am currently running on the beta channel of the windows insider program. The description of it says that Windows 11 will be installed, but when I click on windows update, it just says "you're up to date".

[image]

Before Microsoft removed the pc health check app, I ran it and it showed my device is compatible with windows 11.

So why is windows 11 not installing?

My current OS information My current OS information
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set your Insider Account to the Development Channel. That is faster than Beta. Beta will work at some point, but Development channel should happen right away.

I am in the development channel and on Windows 11 Insider.

Comment: Windows 11 is only currently found on the Dev Channel.

Comment: I started with and continue use the Development Channel  (more suited to technical users) and have been on Windows 11 since late June.  Today it upgraded to 22000.65.  So I think Dev Channel should work.

Comment: The description in the windows beta channel says it will install windows 11, that why I was confused.

Comment: You need to be in the Development channel to get Windows 11 right away. It will come to the Beta channel, just later as I said in m answer.

Comment: Just beware, currently it seems to be impossible to leave dev and go to beta, release or leave insider without a clean reinstall and loose all data.

Comment: You can change from Dev to Beta and not loose anything. I did this in response to a Windows Insider email.

Answer (score 0):

We know it's coming to the beta channel this month so you won't be waiting for much longer. Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fGLp7wpJSc